# Angular2 + firebase-admin sdk

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-admin

When i try to use firebase-admin SDK in my angular2 project i get this error

```
ERROR in ./~/firebase-admin/lib/auth/token-generator.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jsonwebtoken' in '/home/koucky/git_projects/zlepsito-web/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth'
 @ ./~/firebase-admin/lib/auth/token-generator.js 7:10-33
 @ ./~/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth.js
 @ ./~/firebase-admin/lib/auth/register-auth.js
 @ ./~/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

I installed firebase-admin via npm and in my app.module.ts i tryed to use it like this `import 'firebase-admin'` or `var admin = require("firebase-admin");` both ways produce that error.

I have followed: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

app.module.ts

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://myapp-99f41.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Does anyone know what to do, or is able to provide a snippet how to use firebase-admin SDK with angular2 project?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you followed the setup https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup ?

Comment: Yes i have. :( I downloaded serviceAccountKey.json, and set `admin.initializeApp` as described. Still producing that error :(

Comment: Have you made sure you're actually importing the `key.json` file? Seems like that's where the issue lies

Comment: Yes iam sure. Even when i only add `var admin = require("firebase-admin");` it produce error.

Comment: Have you find any solution, yet?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem. Got one step further, but still not all the way.

Did a

```
npm install jsonwebtoken --save
```

which made the jsonwebtoken error disapear. Next error: missing 'dns', which was solved with:

```
npm install dns --save
```

Now i get an error saying 'Invalid left-hand side in assignment'.

I have used this method to call initializeApp instead of the key.json.

Comment: Actually i did try that also, but i think that it is not a good way to fix this. :(